# dplyr for rowwise quantiles

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df of strata, each of which has 1000 samples from a posterior distribution of the estimates from that stratum.

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(lapply(seq(1, 1000), rnorm, n=100))
colnames(mydf) <- paste('s', seq(1, ncol(mydf)), sep='')
```

I want to add columns for a few quantiles of the distribution for each row. In classic R, I'd write this.

```
quants <- t(apply(mydf, 1, quantile, probs=c(.025, .5, .975)))
colnames(quants) <- c('s_lo', 's_med', 's_hi')
mydf <- cbind(mydf, quants)
```

I suspect there's a direct way to do this in `dplyr` (maybe `rowwise`?) but my attempts have failed. Ideas?

Comment: `plyr::adply` may be a better choice: `adply(mydf, 1, function(d) quantile(d, c(.025, .5, .975)))`

Comment: Check out package `matrixStats` (in particular the `rowQuantiles` function). It's way faster than using for/apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dplyr` is not optimized for row-based calculations like that. Though you *can* do this with `rowwise()`, I recommend against it: performance will be abysmal. Your best speed will likely be with something that expects a `matrix`, and can operate on the rows. I suggest `apply`.

Instead of dealing with a 100x1000 `data.frame`, for brevity I'll go with 5 columns:

```
set.seed(2)
mydf <- as.data.frame(lapply(seq(1, 5), rnorm, n=10))
colnames(mydf) <- paste('s', seq(1, ncol(mydf)), sep='')
```

Converting to a `matrix` is only reasonable if all columns are of the same `class`. In this case, they are all `numeric` so we are safe. (If you have non-numeric columns in the dataframe, extract only the ones you need here and bind them back in later.)

```
mymtx <- as.matrix(mydf)
apply(mymtx, 1, quantile, c(0.1, 0.9))
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]       [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
# 10% 1.028912 1.430939 1.999521 0.305907 1.753824 0.03267599 1.934381 1.270504 2.995816 1.489634
# 90% 4.950067 3.807735 4.881554 6.123989 4.886388 5.55628806 4.207605 4.184460 4.406384 3.782134
```

One notable with using `apply` like this is that the result is in row-based form, perhaps transposed from what one would expect. Simply wrap it in `t(...)` and you'll see the columns you might expect.

This can be recombined with the original dataframe using `cbind` or similar function.

This can be done in a pipeline like so:

```
mydf %>%
  bind_cols(as.data.frame(t(apply(., 1, quantile, c(0.1, 0.9)))))
#            s1         s2        s3       s4       s5        10%      90%
# 1   0.1030855  2.4176508 5.0908192 4.738939 4.616414 1.02891157 4.950067
# 2   1.1848492  2.9817528 1.8000742 4.318960 3.040897 1.43093918 3.807735
# 3   2.5878453  1.6073046 4.5896382 5.076164 4.158295 1.99952092 4.881554
# 4  -0.1303757  0.9603310 4.9546516 3.715842 6.903547 0.30590700 6.123989
# 5   0.9197482  3.7822290 3.0049378 3.223325 5.622494 1.75382406 4.886388
# 6   1.1324203 -0.3110691 0.5482936 3.404340 6.990920 0.03267599 5.556288
# 7   1.7079547  2.8786046 3.4772373 2.274020 4.694516 1.93438093 4.207605
# 8   0.7603020  2.0358067 2.4034418 3.097416 4.909156 1.27050387 4.184460
# 9   2.9844739  3.0128287 3.7922033 3.440938 4.815839 2.99581584 4.406384
# 10  0.8612130  2.4322652 3.2896367 3.753487 3.801232 1.48963385 3.782134
```

I'll leave the column naming up to you.

Comment: I am surprised at how much faster this solution is than using the `adply` solution in my comment.

Comment: Sometimes `plyr`, `dplyr`, et al are faster, often more readable, and often more elegant. I dislike having to transpose post-`apply`, but it doesn't get much faster than this without a specific compiled function. Matrices are always faster (I believe) than data.frames, though, so it makes sense.

Comment: You can leave the data.frame to matrix and matrix to data.frame coercion implicit if you want: `cbind(mydf, t(apply(mydf, 1, quantile, c(0.025, .5, .975))))` (though it's good to be aware it's happening).

Comment: The pipeline version is what I was looking for, thx! I'm clear on `t()`, it's part of my original problem spec. I suspect that those of us versed in classic R always think that way.

Answer (score 6):

With `data.frame`-like structures, it's going to be very hard to do rowwise operations efficiently, due to the nature of the data structure. A more efficient solution is probably to reshape the data, do the calculation blockwise in the column, and then join the result back. With `dplyr` + `tidyr`, something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf <- as_data_frame(mydf) %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number())

quants <- mydf %>% 
    gather(sample, value, -id) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarize(q025 = quantile(value, 0.025),
              q500 = quantile(value, 0.5),
              q975 = quantile(value, 0.975)) %>% 
    ungroup()

result <- left_join(quants, mydf)
```

Or, if speed is particularly important, with `data.table`...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)
mydf[, id := .I]
mydf_melt <- melt(mydf, id.vars = 'id')
quants <- mydf_melt[, as.list(quantile(value, c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975))), by = id]
setkey(quants, 'id')
setkey(mydf, 'id')
result <- quants[mydf]
```

Answer (score 4):

`purrr::pmap` can be useful for such cases, iterating in parallel through items in a list, which with a data.frame is operating rowwise. It's more useful if each item contains a parameter or if the function accepts dots, though; otherwise you have to collect a vector with `c`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(47)

mydf <- as.data.frame(lapply(seq(1000), rnorm, n = 100))
names(mydf) <- paste0('s', seq_along(mydf))

# make vector of each row; pass to quantile; convert to list; simplify to data.frame
mydf %>% pmap_df(~as.list(quantile(c(...), c(.025, .5, .975)))) %>% 
    bind_cols(mydf)    # self join to original columns

#> # A tibble: 100 × 1,003
#>      `2.5%`    `50%`  `97.5%`          s1       s2        s3       s4
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1  24.52876 501.2313 974.1547  2.99469634 1.857485 4.8062449 5.412425
#> 2  25.96306 501.5381 975.4427  1.71114251 1.534527 5.0045983 4.029735
#> 3  25.36792 499.8048 974.9472  1.18540528 1.575371 2.1515656 4.537178
#> 4  27.15081 500.9932 975.3688  0.71823499 2.747321 0.9841692 3.774623
#> 5  25.77212 498.7223 974.5576  1.10877555 2.659429 4.6865536 5.448446
#> 6  25.43256 501.2437 973.7319 -0.08573747 2.198829 3.7851258 5.769600
#> 7  24.29993 500.8599 975.5050  0.01451784 1.938954 4.1822894 5.205473
#> 8  25.16637 501.8597 974.8636  1.01513086 3.492032 3.2551467 2.570020
#> 9  25.36332 500.3975 973.3588  0.74795410 3.660735 3.3051286 4.270915
#> 10 27.02456 499.8759 974.3890 -0.46575030 2.771156 3.4292355 3.372155
#> # ... with 90 more rows, and 996 more variables: s5 <dbl>, s6 <dbl>,
#> #   s7 <dbl>, s8 <dbl>, s9 <dbl>, s10 <dbl>, s11 <dbl>, s12 <dbl>,
#> #   s13 <dbl>, s14 <dbl>, ...
```

The names generated by `quantile` are not syntactic, but could easily be replaced by inserting `set_names(c('s_lo', 's_med', 's_hi'))` before `bind_cols`. There are many other ways to reassemble the results, as well, if you like.